# Comparing two select elements values

Tags: javascript, html

I've been been trying to look for a piece of javascript code that compares the values selected by a user in a html form from two `<select>` tags. So if the user selects a minimum value that is greater than the maximum number an alert box in javascript should be displayed.

For example, if the user selects 5 bedrooms from the the MINIMUM bedrooms dropdown list and then 3 bedrooms from the MAXIMUM bedrooms dropdown list, this should not allow the form to be processed when the submit button is clicked. But is fine when 3 is selected from the MINIMUM dropdown list and 5 from the MAXIMUM dropdown list.

```
<form name="search" action="page3.php" method="GET">
    <select name="minimumBeds">
       <option value="1"> 1 </option>
       <option value="2"> 2 </option>
       <option value="3"> 3 </option>
       <option value="4"> 4 </option>
       <option value="5"> 5 </option>
    </select>


    <select name="maximumBeds">
       <option value="1"> 1 </option>
       <option value="2"> 2 </option>
       <option value="3"> 3 </option>
       <option value="4"> 4 </option>
       <option value="5"> 5 </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: [Alert boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alert_dialog_box#Criticism) are terrible from a usability stance. Better to highlight the inputs and put the message in the page. Prepackaged validators (such as [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)) make this easy to achieve. You can also use JS to make it impossible to select invalid options by disabling them, though this too creates usability concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify it, let's suppose those `<select`>s have `id`

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value, 10)  > 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value, 10)) 
{
    alert('ERRROR');
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zw4sT/)

Comment: hi @gdoron should I put this inside a `<script type="text/javascript">` of the `<head>` tag?

Comment: i take it 'min' and 'max' are the id, but was does 10 mean?

Comment: That's the radix, it defines the number base of the int that you want to parse. See [the parseInt() entry at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: it doesn't seem to work :s I gave the `id` in the `select` tag. Am I meant to give an `id` for ech `<option>` element instead?

Comment: @user1135192. I added a live demo. Sorry for being rude but maybe you should learn `javascript`... ?

Comment: @gdoron thanks for the demo. I'm not very experienced programmer in javascript. I just tried the code in your demo, it doesn't work in mine. Maybe is because I have put `$('select').change(check);` in the wrong place. Where should I put this line of code. I've put everything else inside `<script type="text/javascript">`. Also is that line of code in php? Thanks

Comment: If you're not using the jQuery library it won't work in quite the same way as gdoron wrote it. Take a look at the lower-left panel to see how to attach the `onchange`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zw4sT/2/).

Comment: @gdoron, Gordon, I think you may have dyslexia.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve your end result with the following, though I'm trying to prevent the possibility of errors happening, rather than firing an alert after the fact:

```
var minB = document.getElementById('min'),
    maxB = document.getElementById('max'),
    min, max;

function setLimits(elem, other) {
    var opts = other.getElementsByTagName('option');
    if (elem.id == 'min') {
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.selectedIndex; i++) {
            opts[i].disabled = 'disabled';
        }
    }
    else if (elem.id == 'max') {
        for (var i = opts.length-1; i>elem.selectedIndex; i--) {
            opts[i].disabled = 'disabled';
        }
    }
}

minB.onchange = function() {
    setLimits(minB, maxB);
};
maxB.onchange = function() {
    setLimits(maxB, minB);
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zw4sT/1/).

This assumes that the `option` elements will be identical between the two `select` elements. Effectively it prevents someone from selecting a maximum number of bedrooms that's less than their minimum (and vice versa).

---

**Edited** the code to allow for changes to the selection to re-enable the options, using an `if`/`else` block:

```
var minB = document.getElementById('min'),
    maxB = document.getElementById('max');

function setLimits(limit, opts, lower, upper) {
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        opts[i].disabled = lower;
    }
    for (var i = limit; i < opts.length; ++i) {
        opts[i].disabled = upper;
    }
}

function setLowerLimit(limit, elem) {
    var opts = elem.getElementsByTagName('option');
    setLimits(limit, opts, 'disabled', false);
}

function setUpperLimit(limit, elem) {
    var opts = elem.getElementsByTagName('option');
    setLimits(limit+1, opts, false, 'disabled');
}

/* Traditional event registration used to illustrate the above only.
 Production code should use a more modern method (addEventListener/attachEvent, 
 wrapped in a convenience function to make it work across browsers).
 */
minB.onchange = function() {
    setLowerLimit(minB.selectedIndex, maxB);
};
maxB.onchange = function() {
    setUpperLimit(maxB.selectedIndex, minB);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zw4sT/4/).

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`for () { }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange).
- [`option` HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option).